# How to return value from function processing observable of RXJS in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-observable

I have a login view in Angular. I have made:

1. an **UserService** to fetch User Data.
2. an **AuthService** for checking valid User.

So from login view, I pass the username to **AuthService** and it contacts with **UserService** for the data and manipulates data and return a `boolean` value whether the user is valid or not.

code goes below from login view is as follows:

**AuthenticationService:**

```js
this.authenticationService.checkValidLogin(userName,password);
```

**AuthenticationService:**

```js
checkValidLogin(username: string, password: string) {
    this.userService.getUserByEmail(username).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(data => data.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.doc.id, ...c.payload.doc.data() })))).subscribe(res => {
        if (res[0].password === password) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I have return `true` or `false` but that wont return to the method..!!

I want to return `true` or `false` value from subscription or what I am missing here?

Comment: Is the data that you receive from userService an array? I'm asking since you have invoked a map operation on it
 `data.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.doc.id, ...c.payload.doc.data() })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the code is asynchronous, you have to return the `Observable` and subscribe to it when you want to check its validity.

```
checkValidLogin(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.userService.getUserByEmail(username).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(data => data.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.doc.id, ...c.payload.doc.data() }))),
// map result to true or false
map(res => {
      if (res[0].password === password) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    })
);
```

Then when you want to use it:

```
this.authenticationService.checkValidLogin(userName,password).subscribe(valid => {
  console.log(valid); // do your logic here of everything that determines if it's valid or not
});
```

Comment: I will check and let you know..!!

Answer (score 0):

Kindly add return before `this.userService.getUserByEmail` as below.

```
checkValidLogin(username: string, password: string){
return this.userService.getUserByEmail(username).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(data => data.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.doc.id, ...c.payload.doc.data() })))).subscribe(res => {
  if (res[0].password === password) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

I would also suggest to just `return res[0].password === password` as it returns a boolean value

Comment: Thanks for the answer will check and let you know as its simplier solution will approve this if it works..!!

Comment: This won't work, in this case we are returning a `Subscription` for the method and inside of the `Subscription` we are returning `true` or `false`.